# Run xeyes in Docker over Boot2Docker on OS X

Tags: xorg, docker

I seem to have a thing for yak shaving.

I have XQuartz 2.7.7 (xorg-server 1.15.2) running on my Mac with Yosemite. I can run xeyes locally. I have a Docker image with xeyes installed. I build it with the following Dockerfile and tag it `kojiromike/xapps`:

```
FROM debian:jessie
RUN apt-get -qqy update \
 && apt-get -qqy install xauth x11-apps --no-install-recommends
```

I've tried the following attempts to get xeyes running in the container to show up on my local display:

I started boot2docker with `tmp` shared so I could access .X11-unix. A tiny bit of extra work is needed because of [boot2docker issue 678](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/678):

```
boot2docker --vbox-share=/tmp=tmp up
boot2docker ssh <<< 'sudo mount -t vboxsf tmp /tmp'
```

First, I just tried disabling the security mechanisms using the XQuartz interface:

[image]

I assumed I didn't need to *Allow connections from network clients* because I was trying to use a UNIX socket. First attempt:

```
$ docker run -it -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY \
  kojiromike/xapps xeyes
Error: Can't open display: unix:0
```

Next, I tried using xauth:

```
$ docker run -it -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY \
  -e XAUTH="$(xauth nextract - $DISPLAY)" kojiromike/xapps \
  sh -c 'printf "%s" "$XAUTH" | xauth nmerge - && xeyes'
Error: Can't open display: unix:0
```

I'm running out of things to try. I've read [Jessica Frazelle's Blog](https://blog.jessfraz.com/posts/docker-containers-on-the-desktop.html), but it seems like she's working directly on the Docker host, so maybe doesn't have the boot2docker issue I have.

What other steps do I need to connect to my local X server, across boot2docker, from a docker container?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753/can-you-run-gui-apps-in-a-docker-container

Answer (score 0):

Look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/36190462/304690 in particular set:

`DISPLAY=$IPADDR:$DISP_NUM`